# Calling a JavaScript function from another file in Ruby on Rails API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a **utilities.js** file with a bunch of useful functions. I'm trying to call those functions in some other **.js** files and I'm getting an **Uncaught Reference Error**

Here's my **utilities.js** functions I want to call outside, the **callee**

```
this.getProductContainer = function(product, img_path) {
  if (img_path === null) {
    img_path = 'http://placehold.it/800x500';
  }
  return '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature product-in-grid">' + '<div class="thumbnail">' + '<img src="' + img_path + '" alt="Foto de ' + product.DescArtigo + '">' + '<div class="caption">' + '<h4>' + product.DescArtigo + '</h4>' + '<h5>' + product.PVP + '€</h5>' + '<p>' + '<a href="/product/' + product.CodArtigo + '" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>' + '</p>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>';
};

this.getProductContainer2 = function(product, img_path) {
  if (img_path === null) {
    img_path = 'http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff';
  }
  return '<div class="item  col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"> <div class="thumbnail"> <img id="img-artigo-' + product.CodArtigo + '" class="group list-group-image" src="' + img_path + '" alt="" /> <div class="caption"> <a href="/product/' + product.CodArtigo + '"><h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading one-line-elipsis">' + product.DescArtigo + '</h4></a> <div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> <p class="lead">' + (product.PVP * (product.IVA / 100.0 + 1)).toFixed(2) + '€</p> </div> <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> <a class="add-to-cart-btn btn btn-success" data-id-artigo="' + product.CodArtigo + '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Adicionar</a> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>';
};

this.getImageFromProduct = function(idProduct) {
  var url_img;
  url_img = 'http://localhost:3000/image/id_produto/' + idProduct;
  return $.ajax(url_img, {
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(err) {
      console.log("error fetching top.");
      return console.log(err);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var e;
      try {
        if (data !== null) {
          return $('#img-artigo-' + idProduct).attr('src', data.image.url);
        }
      } catch (_error) {
        e = _error;
        return console.log(e);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

And here's the **caller**(category.js)

```
function getProdutosCategoria(id_cat){
    var url_prods_categoria = null;
    //if(is_subcategoria)
        //url_prods_categoria = base_url_primavera + '/artigos/categoria/'+id_cat+'/subcategoria/'+id_subcat;
        //else
    url_prods_categoria = base_url_primavera + '/artigos/categoria/'+id_cat;

    $.ajax({
        url: url_prods_categoria,
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("error fetching products of categorie");
            console.log(err);
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            //console.log("success.");
            var artigos_temp = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#artigos-container').html('');
            if(artigos_temp.length == 0)
                $('#artigos-container').append('<i>Não existem artigos nesta categoria...</i>');
            else
                for(var  i in artigos_temp){
                    artigos[artigos_temp[i].CodArtigo] = artigos_temp[i];
//HERE ------->     var top_element = getProductContainer2(artigos_temp[i], null);//utilities.js
                    $('#artigos-container').append(top_element);
                    //getImageFromProduct(artigos_temp[i].CodArtigo);
                }
        },
        type: 'POST'
    });
}
```

Any idea in how I can call that function on my category.js? Do I need to initialize anything on my Ruby on Rails API?

Regards

**config/initialize/assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( utilities.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( categoria.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( product.js )
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( profiles.js )
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( cart.js )

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( product.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( categoria.css )
```

and I ran

```
rake assets:precompile
```

**assets/javascript/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ./utilities
//= require_tree ./common
```

No errors

Comment: Are you sure that `utilities.js` is being included in your asset bundle? What is `this` inside `utilities.js`?

Comment: How do I make sure if it is on my asset bundle? 
I added this: `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( utilities.js )` to my **assets.rb** in config/initializers. 
Is that what you meant?

Comment: How about `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`?

Comment: @muistooshort `
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ./utilities
//= require_tree ./common`

Comment: And you are including the JavaScript in the page in question? Have you checked what `this` is in `utilities.js`?